# How do I change the color of TableView and Button controls in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder, ios

I designed a web app for iPhone and am now trying my hands at a native Objective-C version, and I'd like to retain some continuity with my original design. Since my web version uses CSS, I was able to customize the color palette, even though the UI was designed to imitate a native iPhone UI.  I'd like to use a similar color scheme for my native app, but it doesn't seem so easy out of the box.  I've gone through a couple tutorials and played around a bit with **Interface Builder**, inspecting the individual settings available for each control.  My biggest questions are:

1. Is it possible to (or how do I) change the color of a **Round Rect Button**?
2. Is it possible to (or how do I) change the color of cells in a **Table View**?
3. Where in the Cocoa Touch Library can I find the standard iOS UI buttons, e.g. the green "Call Back" and red "Delete" buttons in the native voice mail?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Nope, I don't think so. And you probably shouldn't anyways. In my opinion it's better to rather stay consistent with the OS and not the web... What you can do is to use a custom image.
2. `UITableViewCell` has a property named `backgroundView`, which is only present if you have a grouped style. This view has -- just like every other view -- a background color. If you don't have this and want to color individual cells, build a custom cell where you put in a view as background view.
3. As far as I know, they are not publicly available. However, you may find a lot of template images etc on the web that you can use.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding #3, what about the confirmation dialogs that pop up in several apps, e.g. when you want to delete something? Are those all emulated with images, and not available in the SDK?

Comment: These alert panes are all `UIAlertSheet`instances.